# Array size using jsonpath expression - Stefan Goessner JsonPath

Tags: java, arrays, json, size, jsonpath

I'm having a problem with finding an array or list size using Stefan Goessner's JsonPath. I'm using the version json-path-2.0.0.

My jsonpath expression is `$.orders.length` and JSON looks something like this:

```js
{
  "orders" : [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Its failing with the following error:

```
com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Property ['length'] not found in path $['orders']
```

And I tried with `$.orders.length()` too which is again failing with the below error:

`com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Property ['length()'] not found in path $['orders']`

Please suggest me how to get the length of the array using Goessner's JsonPath expression.

**[EDIT]** Following is how I'm obtaining the configuration:

```
    com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration conf = com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL);
    DocumentContext documentContext = JsonPath.using(conf).parse(orderJson);
    Object val = documentContext.read(jsonPathExpression);
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

It seems that support for returning the `length()` of an array was only [added in version 2.1.0](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/issues/88) of the jayway json-path library.

Based on some quick tests, the `$.orders.length()` expression seems to work with both version 2.1.0 and version 2.2.0, so I think you just need to upgrade your dependency version in order to fix the error you are seeing.

Comment: A small correction, seems that it should be $.orders.length (without ()), just tested and works fine for me

Comment: @AlexRewa I tried and it doesn't work on my side with the error message ```java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.length"```. But ```"$.length()"``` works fine

Comment: @VõQuangHòa, weird... seems it depends on JsonPath implementation.

Comment: `$.length()` works on json-path 2.7

Answer (score 4):

with **webclient** in **spring webflux**

```
....
 .jsonPath("$.length()").isEqualTo(2);
...
```

Comment: I used your solution in the following way & it worked like a charm!
This was to specifically check if an array was empty & has zero objects but is not null.

resultActions.andExpect(jsonPath('$.benefitsSummaryResponse.financialData.limitList.length()', is(0)) )

Answer (score 0):

The way to count number of elements in json array
this is how i solve it

`myJson` ->My Json that inside it exist an array

`fieldPath` -> the path to the array

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

JSONObject myJson;

    public long CountFields(String fieldPath) {
      String onlyMyArray=JsonPath.parse(myJson).read(fieldPath).toString();
      JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(onlyMyArray);
      return jsonArray.length();
                       }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
            JsonPath js = new JsonPath(response);
           List values = js.getList("Mention the path of the json here");
           int size= values.size();
           System.out.println(size);
```

Answer (score -4):

The getList() method of JsonPath can be used effectively to convert the array into a list of objects that can then be used with .size()

```
 // convert each item in the Json array to be an item of the orderItems list
List orderItems = someResponse.jsonPath().getList("orders");

// So now because we have the size of the list, we also have the size of the original array
int orderCount = orderItems.size());
```

Comment: Please always add an explanation to the code. it will improve the quality of the answer

Comment: This is the most downvoted useful and correct answer I've ever seen on StackOverflow.  the getList() method of JsonPath was extremely useful to me and this is actually the answer I used to solve the problem.  I'm cleaning up this answer so that hopefully it can climb back up from -6 LOL